# Why does a terraform deployment of a GAE .NET service fail despite specifying the app.yaml file path?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, .net-core, terraform

I have a .NET 6 application which is configured as specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/runtime#dotnet_versions)

The terraform being used to create the service has the following added to the deployment section:

```
    cloud_build_options {
        app_yaml_path = "/app.yaml"
    }
```

as specified [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/app_engine_flexible_app_version#app_yaml_path)

Despite this I'm still getting this error in the build log:

```
No valid .NET Core runtime version found for the app or it is not a supported app.
```

I had this error before and assumed it was because the application had been upgraded to .NET 6 but the necessary addition of the app.yaml file was not included.

Here are the variants of the app.yaml path I've tried with no luck:

- /app.yaml
- app.yaml
- ./app.yaml

The zip file used by the deployment has been downloaded from the GCP bucket and it has been verified that app.yaml exists in the root.

Extra supporting information for this question has been added [here](https://github.com/benfranklin79/shared/tree/master/20230725)

Version of GCP provider being used: 4.74.0
Version of terraform: 1.5.3

Comment: Are you able to deploy without Terraform? Can you share your app.yaml file and your project file structure?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Not quite successful with the standard gcloud deployment. Have provided a stripped down version of the application with a log of my failed deployment. Later on will add some more info to the folder about how the original deployment works

Comment: If you are not able to deploy with the command line, start by fixing this, and then automate with terraform.